# Is it useless to check whether a window is requested to be closed in full-screen mode?

Tags: sfml, keyboard

Is it still necessary to check if the window is requested to be closed when I prepare a 1920x1080 window, in full-screen mode? How could the user close the window in full-screen mode, when you could not click the X button of the window? I take this code from a book.

```
int main()
{
    // Create a video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);
    // Create and open a window for the game
    RenderWindow window(vm, "Pong", Style::Fullscreen);
    /*
    Some code here
    *******************************
    *******************************
    *******************************
    */
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        /*
        Handle the player input
        *******************************
        *******************************
        *******************************
        */
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
           if (event.type == Event::Closed)
           {
               // Quit the game when the window is closed
               window.close();
           }
        }
        /*
        Update the bat, the ball and the HUD
        ****************************
        ****************************
        ****************************
        */
        /*
        Draw the bat, the ball and the HUD
        ****************************
        ****************************
        ****************************
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [sfml-window-events](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php):

> The sf::Event::Closed event is triggered when the user wants to close the window, through any of the possible methods the window manager provides ("close" button, keyboard shortcut, etc.). This event only represents a close request, the window is not yet closed when the event is received.

Clicking the X button of the window is just one of the ways to send `Closed` events. For example, When `Close()` is called, or if the user presses ALT+F4, `Closed event` will also be raised.